# iOS 14 Document based app adopting SceneDelegate?

Tags: ios, document-based, uiscenedelegate

I'm recently developing a new document based app. The traditional, and by now, the official template is instantiating an UIDocumentBrowser in the AppDelegate; and the official recommendation for document based app to use the document browser as the root view.

However, as the multi-window since iOS 13 introduced the Scene and suggest apps to migrate view life cycle related code to the SceneDelegate.

Thus, I'm wondering, how should an app based app that intending to support multi window, should do in such case. And what's your practical advices?